# Using TFS 2010 SDK to modify label comment

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

Is it possible to use TFS sdk to edit/update the comment on a Label without changing any items associated with the label?

Comment: Do you to edit comment or name of label ?? You can change comment just fine from inside VS.

Comment: I know it can be done from VS. But seems like there is no way of doing it using the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

VersionControlServer.CreateLabel()
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb138611(v=vs.100).aspx

Parameters

label
Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlLabel
**The label definition to create or update.**

itemSpecs
Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LabelItemSpec[]
The item specs included in the label.

options
Type: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.LabelChildOption
Options to handle existing items in a label.

I haven't looked to deep into it so not sure if it really does an update, but you can always remove existing one and create new label - from inside VS you shouldn't be able to tell difference.

To find labels use QueryLabels method.

Comment: I thought this method will help as well but apparently the label comment cannot be updated. It can only be set when creating new labels as the comment field for VersionControlLabel is readonly. In my case, I am working with hundreds of labels with comments exported to xml file from another source, so doing it from VS is not an option.